# Node.js Or EJB?

Tags: node.js

js experts :-)! Can I implement a complex business tier in a web-projects (CRUD Operations, Algorithms, complex calculations and optimisation, loading pictures, interactive user GUI, content export in csv and other formats, time-driven events such as email news, security aspects, and so on) completely with Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. You could use any programming language for that.

Answer (score -2):

The Short answer is yes, and for some of these, Node.js will perform exceptionally well.

Personally I find that Node.js is very well suited to handing real time events, and multi-client/server communication.

When it comes to complex calculations, and business logic, Node.js can get tricky. By it's nature it runs things asynchronously, meaning that some things that you would expect to work, don't. Things like

```
var script = 0;
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
  script = i
}
console.log(script);
```

will return some number between 0 and 9, most likely 0. If you aren't used to it (and sometimes even if you are), it can cause countless headaches. There are ways to get it to work the way you would expect, at the very basic level there are callbacks.

```
var script = 0;
var somefunction = function(i, callback){  
  if(i < 10){
    i++;
    somefunction(i, callback);
  }else{
    callback(i);
  }
}
somefunction(script, function(i){ console.log(i)}
```

There are also libraries that can help with the control flow such as async.js.

Because of this though it can make implementing complex calculations and business logic a bit difficult. In some of the projects I've worked on, we've used python, ruby or PHP for the business logic side of things, and node.js to handle realtime communication with the client.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I have two choices: JE66 with MySQL database or Node.js with CouchDB. I can JE66. But I thought I could learn node.js with Sencha Framework to build beautiful and fast web applications just in javascript. I do not have a lot of time to find out if node.js can meet all requirements on the business logic. Maybe it is better to use JE66 with EJB and mySQL Database? Best regards

Comment: Database choices are very different, I recommend taking a look at http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis for a good overview of noSQL database options. As for what language to choose, I recommend figuring out what your application will do, what features are important to you, and what language best fits those features and needs.

Comment: -1: Your first code sample will always print out `9` to the console. Node.js isn't non-deterministic, as your answer seems to imply. It never blocks for IO operations (except in a few explicit cases), which can make coding tricky sometimes -- when IO and callbacks are involved, things may not always run in the order you would initially expect.